# Xubuntu 13.04 CCC requires reboot?

Tags: 13.04, xubuntu, reboot

CCC requires a reboot every time i enable or disable a screen. since i do it at least 8 times a day, this isn't acceptable for me. How do i get around this issue?!

I'm running the official AMD Catalyst™ 13.4 driver and I'm using sudo amdcccle to start CCC. The system is amd64.

Comment: I don't know about Xfce, but with Unity and Gnome, I used following workaround: I enabled all screens in amdcccle, with a desktop stretched across all of them. Then I used the display settings dialogue in system settings to disable all screens except the one I needed. Maybe, something similar works for you.

Comment: That one is locked. It tells me to use amdcccle.